# How to do multiple has_one model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access the title of a user's role in a view. I want to be able to do this `user.user_details.role.title`.

`user.user_details.role` gives me the error `undefined method`role' for #`

What's wrong with my associations that this is not working?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :role, :through => :user_details
end

class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_details
end
```

Comment: Please post your complete error and btw you should use singular names for `has_one` and `belongs_to` i.e, `user_detail` not `user_details`. You need to change the class name too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming for `UserDetails` model is wrong. Change it to `UserDetail` & also update in the association.

Then you will be able to access the role by `user.user_detail.role`. Because for `has_one` association you have to use singular names.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_detail, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :role, :through => :user_detail
end

class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_detail
end
```

Comment: That helps, but now i get the error `Unknown column 'roles.user_detail_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles`  WHERE `roles`.`user_detail_id` = 1 LIMIT 1`. So i still have my associations not quite right.

Comment: Seems i just had to swing the `has_one/belongs_to`.